# How to remove the last comma from the last item generated from a foreach loop, inside a function

Tags: php, json, function, json-ld

I have seen some similar questions-answers, but i haven't managed to do the trick as of yet. Some people advicing to you implode array with comma, but i don't know to to implement implode in that specific case (even if is possible).
I tried to follow the easiest path, and just remove the 12th character of the echoed html (that freaking comma), but i couldn't store the function it self to a variable.
I would appreciate any help, thanks!

```
<?php
  function jsonbreadcrumbs($home = 'Home') {
  $itemNumber = 1;
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= '<script type="application/ld+json">';
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= '{';
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= '"@context": "http://schema.org",';
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= '"@type": "BreadcrumbList",';
  $root_domain = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
  $jsonbreadcrumbs = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= '"itemListElement": [{';
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= '"@type": "ListItem",';
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= '"position":' .$itemNumber++.',';
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= "\"name\": \"{$home}\",";
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= "\"item\": \"{$root_domain}\"},";
  foreach ($jsonbreadcrumbs as $crumb) {
    $link = ucwords(str_replace(array(".php","-","_"), array(""," "," "), $crumb));
    $root_domain .=  $crumb . '/';
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= '{"@type": "ListItem",';
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= '"position":' . $itemNumber++ . ',';
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= "\"name\": \"{$link}\",";
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= "\"item\": \"{$root_domain}\"},";//<---this last comma,when it belongs to the last item, needs to be removed.
    }
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= ']}</script>';
  return $jsonbreadcrumb;
}
echo jsonbreadcrumbs();
?>
```

Comment: make an array and use json_encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) it with your own character list

```
  foreach ($jsonbreadcrumbs as $crumb) {
    $link = ucwords(str_replace(array(".php","-","_"), array(""," "," "), $crumb));
    $root_domain .=  $crumb . '/';
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= '{"@type": "ListItem",';
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= '"position":' . $itemNumber++ . ',';
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= "\"name\": \"{$link}\",";
    $jsonbreadcrumb .= "\"item\": \"{$root_domain}\"},";//<---this last comma,when it belongs to the last item, needs to be removed.
    }
  $jsonbreadcrumb=trim($jsonbreadcrumb,","); // this removes that trailing comma... 
  $jsonbreadcrumb .= ']}</script>';
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But could you please explain me why it trimmed it only in the last item and not all iterated items?

Comment: @Skeptic  If you read the manual for trim (linked in answer) you'll see that it trims what are considered to be extra characters from each end of the string.  Defaults are things like spaces, nulls,and returns, but since the function lets you specify anything, you can use it to trim off an extra comma ....